# how to detect atomic types using enable_if

Tags: c++

Is it possible to detect  my atomic type is being detected a if a type is atomic using enable_if ?

Currently, my atomic type is anyway to distinguish  being detected as a class type

is there anyway to distinguish it as an atomic type

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "is an atomic type" ? Why do you use `std::is_class` ?

Comment: You can check if a type is a specialization of `std::atomic<T>` for some `T`. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to only take a `std::atomic`, consider using `template<typename T> void set(String v, std::atomic<T> &value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `enable_if` in this case, specialization is enough:

```
// By default, types are not atomic,
template<typename T> auto constexpr is_atomic = false;

// but std::atomic<T> types are,
template<typename T> auto constexpr is_atomic<std::atomic<T>> = true;

// as well as std::atomic_flag.
template<> auto constexpr is_atomic<std::atomic_flag> = true;

// Tests:
static_assert(!is_atomic<int>);
static_assert(is_atomic<std::atomic<int>>);
static_assert(is_atomic<std::atomic_flag>);
```

If you want to branch your compile-time logic based on this attribute, you can use C++17 `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T> auto foo(T& t) {
    if constexpr (is_atomic<T>) /* T is atomic */;
    else /* T is not atomic */;
}
```